# SceneKit – How to make self defined particle effect in Xcode 13?

Tags: swift, xcode, scenekit, arkit, particle-system

I am trying to mock an explosion particle effect in xcode 13 as below style

[image]

because there is no `.scnp` file I can use in xcode 13, I tried to use below code to complete,

```
let particleSystem = SCNParticleSystem()
particleSystem.birthRate = 800
particleSystem.loops = false
particleSystem.blendMode = .alpha         
particleSystem.particleSize = 0.030
particleSystem.emitterShape = SCNSphere(radius: 0.9)
particleSystem.particleColor = .yellow
particleSystem.particleLifeSpan = 0.5
particleSystem.particleImage = "art.scnassets/spark.png"
particleSystem.particleColorVariation = SCNVector4(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0)
```

But the result is not expected.

Can anyone help to give any instruction how to do that?

Comment: SO is not a code writing/designing service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To setup particles in UI, choose SceneKit's `.scn` file in Navigator panel and then add a `Particle System` object from Xcode 13 library pressing <kbd>+</kbd> button (instead of a deprecated `.scnp` file):

[image]